# Decompose one row into multi rows according conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this :

```
ID    A_Kode    B_Kode    C_Kode
--------------------------------
1     10        12        0
2     15        0         0
3     0         16        17
4     0         0         0
```

Require a query which provide this result :

```
ID    Kode 
------------
1     10
1     12
2     15
3     16
3     17
4     0
```

Comment: Have you post your table structure or query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to UNION all rows where exists a not zero value and then add rows with 0 where all columns values are zeroes.

```
select id,A_Kode as Kode from t where A_Kode<>0
union all
select id,B_Kode as Kode from t where B_Kode<>0
union all
select id,C_Kode as Kode from t where C_Kode<>0
union all
select id,0 as Kode from t where A_Kode=0 and B_Kode=0 and C_Kode=0
```

Comment: Perfect, just need an order by id at the end

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `union all` will be good for you?

```
select ID, A_Kode
from tab
union all
select ID, B_Kode
from tab
where B_Kode <> 0
union all
select ID, C_Kode
from tab
where C_Kode <> 0
order by ID
```